# Composer update root package

Tags: package, composer-php

I want to make the system updates based on composer

With updating dependencies no special problems, but how to update the root package, it is not clear

I'm trying to understand the code composer and so far without success

I think a root project put into dependencies and leave only the bare minimum
or download the project archive from the github and manually remake it

Maybe someone faced with such a task

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any way to update the main project.

This is when you've, say, installed a project with `composer create-project proj/name . *` or similar? Running `composer update` of course updates the dependencies, but nothing exists to update the project itself.

One way to do it might be as you say, and make the root project nothing but a `composer.json` file that lists the dependencies, and move the project to operate as a dependency. Bit of a change to the structure though, so this mightn't be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use git to do this. This is currently not possible using composer. I was faced with the same problem.

1. Publish your project on github (or another service)
2. Install git on the server
3. Clone the project from git (using `git clone git@github.com:whatever folder-name`) onto your server wherever you want your root folder located
4. Whenever you need to update the root project, open a git command window from the root project directory, and run `git pull origin v1.0.1`. This will essentially patch the project files from the tag you specify.